# How do I connect Wombat Wallet to my Dapp

Tags: wallet

I'm trying to integrate the Wombat wallet into our DApp. I was told the code is similar to integrating Anchor wallet to a DApp.

Can anyone provide proper code or instructions?

Comment: You should add more information about your DAPP first. Which languages, frameworks, network etc.

Comment: It's in React.Js but what I'm looking for is the library with their code. They should have it accessible somewhere. I think it's similar to Anchor wallets code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this helps: [Wombat UAL](https://github.com/pinknetworkx/ual-wombat)

Other 'official' Wombat-Repos can be found [here](https://github.com/orgs/wombat-tech/repositories).

Comment: How do know if pinknetworx is an official source. The other Wombat repo is definitely official, but I wonder why pinknetworx is not within that repo... I don't want to connect bogus code to expose our users to a scam. Ijs